# How to bypass the compiler's verification of the "where" constraint of a C# method

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

A library that I use contains this method:

```
T TheirMethod<T>() where T : Base; // T must inherit from Base
```

In my code, there is this method:

```
T MyMethod<T>() // it can be any T here
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Base)))
        throw new Exception("I'm fine with crashing at runtime here");
    return x.TheirMethod<T>(); // DOES NOT COMPILE
}
```

Of course this doesn't compile, because the compiler is not smart enough to prove statically that my `T` is a `Base`.
(I cannot add a `where` constraint to `MyMethod` because it implements another thrid-party interface.)

My question is: how can I call it anyway? I'd like this check to be done at runtime.

Comment: Why do you want this? Enable another type and throw an exception at runtime?

Comment: Why `T` can be any type if it crashes with all types other than `Base`?

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just add a type constraint to `Base`, then your reflection code goes away and any runtime exceptions

Comment: The point of a generic is to be able to use *any* time that passes the constraint. In your case there literally *is* no constraint at all, so clients of your app will assume they can pass *any* type, while they get an eception at runtime. That completely breaks the idea of generics. Btw.: **the compiler *is* smart enough to not let you shoot into your own foot.**

Comment: I know how good the benefits of static type checking are, but in some exceptional cases, the power to do things dynamically is needed. Or are you arguing that Microsoft was wrong to include dynamic in the language? Today it solved my problem, so I'm happy they did.

Comment: Who said anything about dynamic being bad? It's actually really useful in a few specialised circumstances. We're saying that you're using it in a bad way.

Comment: Well, obviously you *have* some compile-time type which you use in order to call your own `MyMethod`. So let´s assume you call it like this: `var t = MyMethod<MyType>()`. Here you already know that this is non-sense **at compile-time**. You allow it anyway and let the **runtime** handle that case. Of course this is *possible*. However it´s *not a good idea* to do so.

Comment: In my case I cannot put constraints on MyMethod because it would break the rest of my codebase. It is a method used in an interface used in many places. Why can't you accept that I need to use dynamic here?

Comment: If it breaks the rest of your codebase, then perhaps that needs fixing too. Either that or some refactoring because what you have here is a huge code smell.

Comment: I agree with @DavidG.  You have exposed a flaw in your design, dont put a code smell bandaid on it, fix the source of the problem

Comment: Okay, you state that your current code would break if you´d appended the constrauint. So please show some of this code that would break. I can´t imagine how you call your own method, if not whiith a **compile-time**-type.

Comment: Why does everyone on stackoverflow want me to fix design problems in code that's not even mine instead of just accepting that a solution exists? Things weren't always like this... Look, of course there's a deeper flaw here, but it's outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: `"Why does everyone on stackoverflow want me to fix design problems"` -- because most of us are experienced programmers who have taken the "easy way" early in our careers and learned our lessons.  We're just sharing wisdom here, you might be wise to listen to some of it...

Comment: The point is: we still don´t have a clue about your actual problem, this is *why* you think you need that. If you´d provide a code-sample about how you use that method...

Comment: Or in other words: there seems to be something that we do *not* know but *you do*. So it would be really nice, if you would provide that hidden knowledge, this is *why* such a change would break your code. Not just saying: it doesn´t work.

Comment: You have several highly skilled developers here (with decades of experience!) telling you not to do this but you are insisting it's not possible without providing any evidence. As a dev manager, if you came to me with this code, I would expect a solid reason backed with evidence that this is the only way.

Comment: I think you are correct: this is my fault. I should have made more clear in my question what the problem is and is not about. I mentioned that the first function was in a library, not because it's true, just so that everyone gets that changing it is not possible and out of scope of this question. I should have done the same with the second function, but I messed up and that attracted the "you shouldn't be doing that" squad. The question is only about getting rid of the where constraint. Valid answers to such a question exist and have already been given (and downvoted).

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use Reflection to call the Method. But you should consider the performance Impact of Reflection.

```
T MyMethod<T>()
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Base)))
        throw new Exception("I'm fine with crashing at runtime here");

    return (T) typeof(TheirClass).GetMethod("TheirMethod").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T)).Invoke(x, null);
}
```

Comment: That's... just the same as with dynamic, except that it's more difficult to write and to read.

Comment: @EldritchConundrum not the same. `dynamic` has to spin up the DLR which is basically a mini-version of the compiler. It has to compile the method, track the different call sites and various other things. Thats expensive. Reflection is expensive too, but given the choice I think I'd forgo dynamic even if it did provide a working solution that looked cleaner.

Answer (score -2):

Use the special `dynamic` type that delays type constraints checking until runtime:

```
return ((dynamic)x).TheirMethod<T>();
```

(I figured out the answer half-way through writing my question, but I'm posting it anyway, in case it can be useful to someone.)

Comment: This compiles and runs fine... If you want to understand why, read about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic